# How to add manually a plugin in MAUI framework

Tags: maui

I am trying to manually add a plugin to my .NET MAUI project. The plugin is located in the plugins/my_plugin/ directory, and my project is in the src/ directory. I have attempted to use the following command to add the package:

dotnet add package Borescope --source ..\plugins\my_plugin
However, this command doesn't seem to work as expected, and I'm encountering issues.

Could someone provide guidance on the correct way to manually add a local plugin to a .NET MAUI project? I've checked the official documentation and online resources, but I couldn't find a clear solution.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What specific plugin are you trying to install?  What specific issues are you having?

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong but do you have a .NET core library in your hard drive somewhere that you would like to refer to as a reference for your MAUI project?

Comment: What do you mean by "plugin"?

Answer (score 0):

dotnet add package  --source 
: Replace this with the name of your local plugin. For example, if your plugin is named MyPlugin.MAUI, you'd use that here.
--source : This specifies the source from which to add the package. In this case, you're specifying the local path where your plugin resides. Replace  with the actual path to your plugin. For example, ..\plugins\MyPlugin\bin\Release.

Full Example:
dotnet add package MyPlugin.MAUI --source ..\plugins\MyPlugin\bin\Release\

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thats the problem bot i cannot find any documentation about that 